# Inserting data in table with umlaut is not possible

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.2.5 (cqlsh 3.0.2) and trying to inserting data in a small test-database with german characters which is not possible. I get back the message from cqlsh: "Bad Request: Input length = 1"

below is the setup of the keyspace, the table and the insert.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
use test;

CREATE TABLE testdata (
id varchar,
text varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

**This is working:**

```
insert into testdata (id, text) values ('4711', 'test');
```

**This is not allowed:**

```
insert into testdata (id, text) values ('4711', 'töst`);
```

`->Bad Request: Input length = 1`

my locale is :`de_DE.UTF-8`

Does Cassandra 1.2.5 has a problem with Umlaut ?

Answer (score 3):

I just did what you posted and it worked for me.  The one thing that was different however, is that instead of a single quote, you finished 'töst` with a backtick.  That doesn't allow me to finish the statement in cqlsh.  When I replace that with 'töst' it succeeds and I get:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from testdata;

 id   | text
------+------
 4711 | töst
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your reply but it doesnt work for me. the backtick here was my mistake (had some problems fto copy it from my screen) in reality I also used insert into testdata (id, text) values ('4711', 'töst'); and this gave me the errormessage. But interessant is that you got the data inserted. do you have an idea why? something with the "locale"?

Comment: Jeremy, I found the problem. The reason was that I am working on a Windows PC with Putty to connect to the linux-system. Per default Putty uses ISO-8859 for the remote Character set which doesnt fit to UTF8 locale form my linux-box. i changed it in putto also to UTF8 and it is working now.

Comment: I had after that another problem with the character set when i loaded my data from a file with the "source" command in cassandra. There I got the same problem. For people who creates a sql-file for inserting in a DB like cassandra take care that when you create an sql-file like me as with a php-schript, you should utf8_encode before writing to the file, otherwise the file has not UTF8-Format and then it gives problems in Cassandra with loading this file with the source statement.My problem is herewith solved.