# Inserting special characters

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to insert special characters in my Cassandra table but I couldn't insert it.
[Inserting data in table with umlaut is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425262/inserting-data-in-table-with-umlaut-is-not-possible)
As mentioned in the link i tried above link even though my character set is UTF8 as mentioned.I'm not able to insert. I've tried using quotes also still didn't work

```
CREATE TABLE test.calendar (
    race_id int,
    race_start_date timestamp,
    race_end_date timestamp,
    race_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (race_id, race_start_date, race_end_date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (race_start_date ASC, race_end_date ASC


insert into test.calendar (race_id, race_start_date , race_end_date , race_name ) values  (501,2016-02-18 05:00:00+0000 ,2016-02-22 05:00:00+0000 ,'Hotel in der Nähe von mir');

ERROR MESSAGE :
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:99 mismatched input '-02' expecting ')' (...race_name ) values  (501,2016[-02]-18...)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't quote your date values, so `2016-02-22 05:00:00+0000` is seen as "2016 minus 02 minus 22 blah blah blah" - an arithmetic operation followed by some random numerical garbage.

Try

```
INSERT .... VALUES(... '2016-02-22 05:00:00+0000', ...)
                       ^------------------------^
```

instead. Note the `'` quotes.