# Cassandra doesn't insert a row with cyrillc text

Tags: sql, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm running query in `cqlsh` console on Windows like:

```
 insert into customer (id, name) values (1, 'іван');
```

but `cqlsh` is exiting without any message and result.
When I change cyrillic value 'іван' to latin 'ivan' - a row is being inserted successfully. 
I tried on Cassandra v. 2.2.7 and 3.7

What's a problem?

Comment: I think this might be an issue with CQLSH rather than Cassandra. Try it via Java etc.. and I expect it will work.

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488457/inserting-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

cqlsh had a problem with utf-8 characters that was [solved in Cassandra 2.2.5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10875)
Try specifying `--encoding=utf8` in your cqlsh options.